# Looking for a cheap skylake laptop with full-speed thunderbolt 3 and good cooling

Tags: laptop, thunderbolt

I plan to use one of the new Thunderbolt 3 external GPU enclosures to connect a GTX 1070 to a laptop.

Obviously the video card of the laptop itself is unimportant, so I'm hoping to save some $$ by getting a laptop with a good CPU but a mediocre graphics card.

However, it has to have good cooling, because a CPU like a 6700HQ can still really cook. So, probably an ultra-thin laptop is not going to cut it. Good ventilation is crucial.

Btw, when I say cheap, I mean awesome quality, but less money than an awesome quality top-of-the-line gaming laptop. Probably an ASUS, Gigabyte, Lenovo or Alienware, and something sporting a GTX 965 or worse would probably be fit the bill.

**EDIT**

I'd really like to see at least one option from the above brands. I probably should have said "must be". Also it should be an HQ or HK CPU or better.

Budget is relative. If there's a Gigabyte laptop which fits the bill and is cheaper than the equivalent Gigabyte laptop with beefy graphics, then we're winning.

Comment: What kind of budget are we talking about here?

Comment: Basically, if it's not saving money compared to an equivalent laptop with beasty graphics, then it defeats the purpose.

Comment: Please note: There has been reports if instability of certain eGPU and laptop combinations, especially the Razer Core may perform suboptimal if paired with a non-prepared (e.g. you can't toggle the internal GPU off) non-Razer laptop with an integrated GPU.

Answer (score 2):

So, there's no budget, so I'm going to stay below $1500. If you have a specific price point to stay below, please comment and I will add more answers.

---

### [Dell XPS 15 9550](http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-15-9550-laptop-b/pd#!tnt-configs)<sup>1</sup>

- **Price:** $1400
- **CPU:** i7-6700HQ
- **RAM:** 8GB DDR4-2133
- **Disk:** 256GB PCIe SSD
- **GPU:** GTX 960M
- **Size:** 15.6" screen, 13.3" chassis.
- **Screen:** 1920 x 1080, no touch (touch available) (Not IPS!)

---

### [Razer Blade Stealth](http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-systems/razer-blade-stealth)<sup>1 2</sup>

- **Price:** $1150
- **CPU:** i7-6500U
- **RAM:** 8GB DDR3-1866
- **Disk:** 256GB PCIe SSD
- **GPU:** Intel HD Graphics 520
- **Size:** 12.5" screen
- **Screen:** 3200 x 1800 IGZO, multi-touch

---

<sup>1</sup>Other configurations available. 
<sup>2</sup>This question was edited after I wrote this answer

Comment: I'd hardly call the 960M a *mediocre* graphics card... not top-of-the-line, sure, but it's not a "meh" card to have. It wastes money, in a laptop that's going to have an external graphics card connected to it anyway - IMO.

Comment: Although I did say GTX965 or lower is good. Basically it is likely to be cheaper than a laptop with a GTX970M or GTX980M, and that's the point. Thanks.

Comment: Please note that the i7-6500U is a 15W dual core processor and thus significantly less powerful than the i7-6700HQ which is a true quad-core with hyper-threading and a much higher allowed TDP of 45W.

Comment: @SEJPM Noted. This was my secondary answer as Adam Wykes' answer was upvoted, so I had assumed that an i7-6500U was acceptable.